# Using the CFF Stage to read an EBCDIC file as a single record

Tags: datastage

I have an EBCDIC file created on z/OS and is SFTPed to the midrange/Linux.  The EBCDIC file has 20 fields.  I’m trying to use the CFF Stage to read records in one field.  Is this possible?  Thanks in advance for any help.

The COBOL copybook has
01  Record
02 FLD_1
02 FLD_2
02 FLF_3
.
.

I want the CFF Stage to read the file entire record.
01  Record

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the copybook with one that has only an 01 level item.  Or replace the table definition with a single field of type Char (or VarChar) of appropriate maximum length.

Comment: Hello Ray.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried creating a copybook with just the 01 level.  When I load that copybook into the CFF stage no "Available Columns" appear in stage.  Also, when I update the CFF stage manually with just the 01 level the stage says the level number must be in the 3 to 49 range.  Your thoughts?  or maybe a workaround?

Comment: OK, try something like:
01 MyRecord.
     03 SingleField PIC X120.

Comment: Hello Ray.  I tried 01, 03, and PIC X120.  I had to change the Reject Mode to Fail for it to work.  unfortunately the compressed fields remained compressed and looks like gibberish.  I suspect because of the PIC X.  Any thoughts or workarounds?